# Is there a way to modify request body in a Symfony kernel event_listener

Tags: xml, symfony, event-listener

My app receives an XML in a request body, but some changes in XML structure are needed before the controller action.

I've made a kernel event listener

```
class TransformRequestPListener {
  public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
  {
  [...]
  }
}
```

declared in service.yml

```
class: .\Listener\TransformListener
arguments: [...]
tags:
  - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

And my question is:

- Can I modify request body (the received XML)?
- How?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
Override the Bundle class is a new way I'm exploring. Maybe I can do something with Compiler Passes as [stated here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#services-configuration) but I've never done something similar. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I managed to modify the content... or something similar.

Using a Kernel Event Listener I recovered the request, make needed transformations and 
I reinitialized the request. I must check it doesn't interfere with anything else. Here's the code:

```
$transformedContent = custom_transform($request->getContent());

$request->initialize(
   $request->query->all(),
   $request->request->all(),
   $request->attributes->all(),
   $request->cookies->all(),
   $request->files->all(),
   $request->server->all(),
   $transformedContent
);
```

Comment: I checked it and it's not fully working. I tried this solution with API Platform to add some variables to the JSON content before it's processed.

The 'initialize' method null some properties of the Request object: languages, charsets, encodings, acceptableContentTypes, pathInfo, requestUri, baseUrl, basePath, method, format. (See: https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/a58dc88d56e04e57993d96c1407a17407610e1df/Request.php#L267)

Some of these properties are necessary for the response format negotiation which caused problems. I ended up using the Reflection API.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the `kernel.request` (`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents::REQUEST`) which uses the `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent` event and update the request through that.

```
$request = $event->getRequest();

$xml = $request->request->get('xml_stuff');

.... perform actions ....

$request->request->set('xml_stuff', $updatedXml);
```

**UPDATE**

With the information that you are using BeSimpleSoapBundle...

It looks like you might be able to override the `SoapWebServiceController::callAction` when generating the request.

You could change..

```
$this->soapRequest = SoapRequest::createFromHttpRequest(
    $this->container->get('request')
);
```

.. to ..

```
$request = $this->container->get('request'); 

$updXml = $request->attributes->get('updated_xml');
$request->attributes->remove('updated_xml');

$updRequest = new Request(
    $request->query->all(), 
    $request->request->all(), 
    $request->attributes->all(), 
    $request->cookies->all(), 
    $request->files->all(), 
    $request->server->all(), 
    $updXml
);

$this->soapRequest = SoapRequest::createFromHttpRequest($updRequest);
```

.. but I'm pretty sure it's not the best way of doing it.

Comment: But I need to modify the body. I can reach the XML using `$request = $event->getRequest()->getContent();` but I'm not able to set modified content.
`

Comment: Ah fair do's. I did see on a site about setting a `$request->attribute` variable to the new `$updatedXML` but I assume you wouldn't want that.

Comment: I'm using http://besim.pl/SoapBundle/index.html and processing XML in body/content. I'm not sure about being able to make it work passing it as a parameter...

Comment: I've never used it so I don't know how it works to be honest. I've added to my answer.

Comment: Actually It's the only way I've found until now. After `$this->soapRequest = SoapRequest::createFromHttpRequest($this->container->get('request'));` I can get the XML with `$this->soapRequest->getSoapMessage()` and modify it before been handled.

But I would like to keep Bundle code untouched. Do you know a way to override `SoapWebServiceController::callAction` in my own Bundle?

Comment: There are details about how to do it here - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html