# How to mutate data with API-Platform events before writting it

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4, api-platform.com

I have a User and a University entity with a ManyToOne relation (one university can have many users). I added a constraint of unicity on the university name to avoid duplicates.

So when I do a PUT HTTP request at the /users/$id route with a payload containing a university name that exist I get this:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'INSA' for key 'unique_university_name'

What I would like is before doctrine writes the entry in the database, to mutate it if it does already exist.

To do so I tried to use the event system of API-platform: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events

With the kernel.request events I could access the data but I didn't manage to mutate it. I didn't find a way to change the "content" of Request. I tried also this: [Is there a way to modify request body in a Symfony kernel event_listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776661/is-there-a-way-to-modify-request-body-in-a-symfony-kernel-event-listener) and I ended up with this error.

> Serialization for the format html is not supported

I wanted to do it with the kernel.view events such as PRE_VALIDATE, POST_VALIDATE or PRE_WRITE but they are not triggered from some reason.

Am I using the right approach? What should I do to add the university to the user if it already exists based on its "name"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve your problem I see 3 possibilities:

- Add a custom denormalizer that verify the name and change it on the fly (detailed bellow)
- Add a [custom listener for doctrine](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) on pre-persist event
- Using domain events see [this lib](http://github.com/biig-io/DomainComponent) for example

---

Here is how to create your custom denormalizer:

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface;

final class UniversityDenormalizer implements DenormalizerInterface
{
    private $decoratedDenormalizer;
    private $repository;
    public function __construct(DenormalizerInterface $decorated, UniversityRepository $repository) {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->decoratedNormalizer = $decorated;
    }

    public function denormalize($data, $class, $format = null, array $context = array())
    {
        if ($count = $this->repository->countUniversitiesStartingBy($data['name'])) {
            $data['name'] .= '_' . ($this->repository->countUniversities() + 1);
        }
        return $this->decoratedDenormalizer->denormalize($data, $class, $context);
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null)
    {
        return is_string($data) && University::class === $type;
    }
}
```

You also need to register it as service:

```
App\Serializer\UniversityDenormalizer:
    arguments:
        # Choose the denormalizer depending on your output.
        # For example, for JSON+LD it's "api_platform.jsonld.normalizer.item"
        - '@api_platform.json.normalizer.item'
        - '@App\Repository\UniversityRepository'
    tags:
        # Priority is important but any value more than 8 should be ok
        - { name: serializer.normalizer, priority: 17 }
```

Comment: The custom denormalize didn't work It gave directly error 500 without any message, the doctrine listener on pre persist was not triggered some reason and fortunately the DomainComponent library worked!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to modify your `university` object which is embedded in your `user` entity.

If you are following the docs, and doing it like this, then it won't work, because the main object is a `User` instance.

```
$object = $event->getControllerResult();
$method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();
if (!$object instanceof University || Request::METHOD_POST !== $method) {
  return;
}
```

One way to this is:

```
$object = $event->getControllerResult();
$method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();
if (!$object instanceof User || Request::METHOD_POST !== $method) {
  return;
}

$university = $user->getUniversity();
// modify or replace your university here.
```

Another approach is using a [doctrine event subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html), keep in mind that this gets executed after [entity validation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/validation).